# List of our warnings aka moderator private messages

Tags: feature-request, moderator-messages

Currently, in order to see a warning (Private Moderator Message, it has no other official usage) issued to you in the past, you have to either look for it in your email (fair, but emails might get deleted over time) or look for the inbox item, which can be cumbersome.

What I suggest is that https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/messages or just https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/message (without giving a message ID) will show the list of all messages issued to the currently logged-in user.

Since it's not really commonly used, I don't ask for a link in the profile, but please at least give a way to see the past messages in an easy way.

Comment: Something other than https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox?

Comment: @CaveJohnson umm, yes? I ask for list of very specific items of the inbox, which are moderator messages. (and not in the inbox format, or any UX - just have it listed somehow.)

Comment: Oh ok just curious. Perhaps this fr could be a filter on top of that page. I upvoted btw

Comment: @CaveJohnson thanks, your suggestion did give me an idea. :)

Comment: Why do you want this? As far as I know, the idea is that after serving a suspension, you're supposedly fully rehabilitated and shouldn't be dwelling on things like this?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell history is important, and a way to learn how to avoid same mistakes in the future. We can even see list of all our deleted posts (as 10k users at least) where "shouldn't be dwelling on things like this" also applies.

Answer (score 10):

Just thought of another way to accomplish this: adding filters to our [network profile inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox):

[image: global inbox filters]

One of those filters will be "moderator messages" which will show list of all the messages.