# Add a link to mod messages

Tags: feature-request, moderator-messages

Currently, AFAIK there's no way to access moderator messages, unless digging through one's SE notifications/inbox or emails. Not convenient for old mod messages. Feature request: Add a link to mod messages somewhere in the UI (possibly only if the user has received a mod message, to avoid cluttering the UI).

Comment: I'm disinclined to close hammer it but [How can a user view an (old) moderator message?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369481/how-can-a-user-view-an-old-moderator-message) was a similar request, and the question it was closed as a dupe against [How do we see the private messages that moderators sent us?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94779/how-do-we-see-the-private-messages-that-moderators-sent-us) is worth a look.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek thanks, nice info indeed, I thought that'd be good to clearly make a feature request for it.

Comment: Related request: [List of our warnings aka moderator private messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374301/list-of-our-warnings-aka-moderator-private-messages)